# Use Erlang etop to dump information to a file?

Tags: erlang, erlang-escript

What is the command line options to use Erlang etop to dump Erlang program information to a file?
If this cannot be done in command line, can it be done in an escript?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I found in my Makefile:

```
run_etop:
    erl -name node@127.0.0.1 -setcookie cookie -pa ebin/ -detached -s app
    erl -name etop@127.0.0.1 -noinput -s etop -s erlang halt -output text \
    -setcookie cookie -interval 1 -lines 20 -accumulate true > etop.log
```

I start my application (`app`) on `node@127.0.0.1` and then I start another node (`etop@127.0.0.1`) from which I connect to the first node and where I run etop.

To get list of etop options, try `etop:help()` in erlang console.

Comment: Instead of continuously output data every "interval" time, can etop just output data once?  Your example using "> etop.log" does not cause etop to overwrite the last output data, instead the log file keeps growing.   I looked at etop:help() and cannot find an option to do that.

Comment: You could just use `tail` command to get the last output from the log file.